# How I can detect a value has changed upon a textarea that has been initialized using easyeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have initialized a rich text editor for a textarea using the [easyeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyeditor?activeTab=readme) library:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editor").easyEditor({
         buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright']
     });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/easyeditor@1.2.0/src/easyeditor.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/easyeditor@1.2.0/src/jquery.easyeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

And I want upon a change into the `textarea` to trigger some logic (eg. form validation) how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon multiple attempts to solve the issue, the only any event listener for textarea using this libraries does not work. But using an `EasyEditor` instance you can get a div element instead of the textarea. The textarea element is hidden via css.

Upon this element you can place the input method event listener:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   const editor = new EasyEditor("#editor",{
         buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright']
     });
     
     $(editor.elem).on('input',function(e){
        const target = e.target;
        console.log(e.target);
        document.getElementById("valueDisplay").innerText = $("#editor").val();
     });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/easyeditor@1.2.0/src/easyeditor.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/easyeditor@1.2.0/src/jquery.easyeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>

<div id="valueDisplay"></div>
```

In the example above the `editor.elem` is the editor element that Easyeditor initializes. This one is a `div` element having `contenteditable` true. The underlying textarea is hidden and upon input value the textarea one is syncronized via the Easieditor.

Therefore you can place an input event listener on editors `div`, as shown in the example above. Then you can retrieve the value from the text area.

---

If triggering an ajax values is reccomended to debounce the event callback first. Also for the latest value use the innerHTML of the `editor.elem`. Using the text area you may not be able to read the latext content especially when user continiously provided input.

```js
/**
 * Debounce function as described into:
 * https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/
 *
 * It delays the execution of a function func after wait miliseconds (?)
 * Usefull for avoiding multiple ajax requests triggered from user Input
 *
 * @param func
 * @param wait
 * @return {(function(...[*]): void)|*}
 */
function debounce(func, wait) {
    let timeout;
    return function (...args) {
        const context = this;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait);
    };
}


$(document).ready(function(){
   const editor = new EasyEditor("#editor",{
         buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright']
     });
     
     $(editor.elem).on('input',debounce(function(e){
        const target = e.target;
        console.log(e.target);
        document.getElementById("valueDisplay").innerText = editor.elem.innerHTML
     },100));
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/easyeditor@1.2.0/src/easyeditor.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/easyeditor@1.2.0/src/jquery.easyeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>

<div id="valueDisplay"></div>
```